# Mobile Report - Reporting Services 2016

Tags: relatório, sql-server-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, business-intelligence

Este é o meu primeiro post na comunidade e espero poder colaborar com a minha questão.

Estou trabalhando em um projeto de BI onde preciso mostrar um quantitativo de chamados em um mapa, conforme os modelos que existem prontos, é possível usar uma coluna com o nome dos estados e de alguma forma o `Mobile Reports` aponta corretamente os dados por estados.

No entanto, preciso fazer um mapa dentro do nível dos estados, mostrando as quantidades de chamados por cidades. No caso quais cidades abriram mais chamados.

O problema é que não consegui encontrar no sistema ou na internet qualquer referência sobre como fazer isso a nível de estados e cidades, apenas de países e estados. Inclusive não encontrei informações de como o Mobile Reports trabalha com localizações como dados geográficos ou geométricos.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?